# How do I use std map to map shapes to a class object?

Tags: c++, dictionary, sfml

So I have a vector of objects from my Box class, and I want to map each box to a set of coordinates on the screen so that when you click on a certain area, a specific box will be accessed from the vector. I'm using sfml 2.1 to create rectangles that will serve as the clickable areas. Here is what I have so far:

Board.h (a gameboard that holds the boxes):

```
#pragma once
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <vector>
#include <map>
#include "Box.h"
#include "SFML/Graphics.hpp"
#include "ImageManager.h"

class Board{
public:
    Board(ImageManager &im);
    ~Board();

    void FillVectors();
    void FillMap();

    std::vector<Box> &GetBoxes();

    sf::Sprite GetGameBoard();
private:
    sf::Sprite gameBoard;

    ImageManager &imgr;

    std::vector<sf::RectangleShape> rectangles;
    std::vector<Box> boxes;

    std::map<sf::Vector2f, std::vector<Box>> boxMap;
};
```

And in Board.cpp:

```
void Board::FillVectors(){
for(int i = 0; i < 9; i++){
    sf::RectangleShape rectangle(sf::Vector2f(80,80));
    Box box;

    rectangles.push_back(rectangle);
    boxes.push_back(box);
}
for(int i = 1; i < boxes.size() + 1; i++){
    std::cout << boxes[i].GetName();
    rectangles[i].setPosition((i * 20) + 10, (i * 20) + 10);
}
```

}

```
void Board::FillMap(){
    for(std::map<sf::Vector2f, std::vector<Box>>::const_iterator it = boxMap.begin(); it != boxMap.end(); ++it){
        for(int i = 0; i < boxes.size(); i++){
            boxMap[rectangles[i].getOrigin()];
        }
    }
}
```

No errors are thrown, but I'm really lost as to what to do from here. Is a std::map even the correct way to link an area on the screen to an object?

Comment: You need a spatial index http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spatial_database

Comment: @nikitoz, it's just tic tac toe, not an rpg. I'm looking for something more efficient than a giant list of if statements, but perhaps not something as complex looking as a spatial index.

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for an associative array or map.  Since the map will contain links to the boxes, it cannot be placed in a box class.

One way to do this is to create a structure for the coordinates and use pointers to the boxes:

```
struct Coordinate; // Forward declaration, you provide the details.  
typedef std::map<Coordinate, Box *> Box_Container;
```

This is a common technique for making index tables that point to records.

*Note:  A simpler design uses box numbers as an index into a `std::vector`.*

**Edit 1: Example of structure**

```
struct Coordinate
{
  int x; // or horizontal
  int y; // or vertical
};
```

Comment: Alright I'm unfamiliar with structs, so is there a quick pseudocode you can provide for this example?

Comment: You are using `class`es, but you are not familiar with `struct`s?  The difference between the two is the default access:  `class` has `private` as default, `struct` has `public` access as default.  Usually the terms can be interchanged.

Comment: You will see why it is a wrong idea, if you think about predicate, used in std::map for your struct

Comment: The plain structure I presented will not work with `std::map` as is, because the structure needs `operator==` and `operator<` defined.

Comment: On the note, I realize that a vector would be simpler, but I want to make the boxes clickable. Essentially I'm trying to map an `sf::RectangleShape` to a `box`. So I need to incorporate the sf namespace into my boxes, but I'm not sure how to actually link (or map) an sf object to a regular object.

Comment: Many windowing systems allow you to associate a function that gets called when a widget, or window is clicked.  In your case, it would be a box that gets clicked.  This may be easier if you use a GUI framework.

Answer (score 0):

For a tic tac toe, just declare a matrix 3x3 (2d array) which will correspond to your gaming field. All cells have equal size. Each cell may contain an object of some type. To find cell number corresponding to coordinate (x, y) : `i = x/cell_size; j = y/cell_size`; where / is an integer division, i - number of row, j - column

Comment: By matrix do you mean a 2d array?

Comment: Yes I agree with this concept. You get the coordinate when clicked, then you iterate through your boxes to find one which has been clicked. The coordinate is just a property of the Box object. Obviously for the search or the way you arrange in a data structure for efficient search your boxes is a different matter. The arrangement of the boxes on the screen and the way are in a collection not necessarily related.

Comment: @xebo we're talking about tic tac toe game, I'm not sure what do you mean by "box arrangement". I think efficient data structure for this case is just an ad hoc grid.

Comment: Ok, it didn't come through that is a simple tic tac toe. Then yes a simple formula will do. (Probably I was overthinking it, or wanted to find a generic solution.) Box arrangement, i thought about randomly arranged boxes on the screen.